# Formatting of decimals in dynamic LINQ to Entities "where" clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using LINQ to Entities, and I'm creating a generic class that can tag on dynamic "Where" clauses to queries based on the fields the user wants to search on in the app.

This could be used on **any** type of Entity in my database, so I'm using string-based Where clauses.

By using System.Linq.Dynamic, I've got some basic examples working, e.g.

String field contains:

```
var data = db.Products;
var query = String.Format("{0}.Contains(@0)", filter.property);
data = data.Where(query, filter.value);
```

Number field greater than:

```
var data = db.Products;
var query = String.Format("{0} > @0", filter.property);
data = data.Where(query, filter.value);
```

These examples both work fine.

I now need to create a decimal "equals to", but the issue is that the currency value in the database might be 10.3125, but it's displayed in the app UI as 10.31, so if a user wants to restrict where the price is equal to "10.31", no results will be returned.  What I need to do is perform a comparison by restricting the number of decimal places to two when querying the database, and comparing that to the user's entered decimal value, something like this:

```
var data = db.Products;
var query = String.Format("Decimal.Round({0}, 2).Equals(@0)", filter.property);
data = data.Where(query, filter.value);
```

Where "filter.property" is the column/field name, and "filter.value" contains the decimal value.

However, this throws a runtime error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Argument types do not match

I can't seem to find many decent examples of string-based LINQ Where clauses involving decimal numbers, or formatting of numbers.

Are there any suggestions on how to get this working? As a last resort, I could bring back all the data from the table, format the decimal numbers appropriately in memory, then finally add the Where clauses to the in-memory result set, but that would be a lot heavier on resources.  Surely there's a way to do this dynamically with LINQ to Entities?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use a range check, where the range is the filter value +/- 0.005:

```
10.305 < value <= 10.315
```

It's also better to do it this way, because if you round the database value first, the query optimizer can't use indexes any more. The search isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).